# For loop only compares the first part of the arrays instead of whole

Tags: c++, arrays

Hi I'm making a basics shape library as a practice for learning C++, I'm making the triangles class and am making a function for checking whether two triangles are congruent/ similar. However the for loop for comparing the two triangles only compares the first elements of the array.

I am pretty new to C++ so I don't know what to try in order to fix this.

```cpp
bool Triangle::checkCongruentWith(Triangle comparee){
  float* sides1 = sides;
  float* sides2 = comparee.sides;
  std::sort(sides1, sides1+3);
  std::sort(sides2, sides2+3);
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    std::cout<<sides1[i]<<" "<<sides2[i]<<std::endl;
    if(sides1[i]!=sides2[i]){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

bool Triangle::checkSimilarWith(Triangle comparee){
  float* angles1 = angles;
  float* angles2 = comparee.angles;
  std::sort(angles1, angles1+3);
  std::sort(angles2, angles2+3);
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    std::cout<<angles1[i]<<" "<<angles2[i]<<std::endl;
    if(angles1[i]!=angles2[i]){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: One thing to note is that comparing floats for exact equality/inequality almost never does what you'd want it to do, because the round-off error introduced by most floating-point math operations means that the values likely won't be exactly equal to each other (even when, mathematically speaking, they should be).    Here's an article on the subject that might be useful:  https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/

Comment: This is also a good time to learn to use the debugger.  If you single-stepped through your code and looked at the values of angles[0] and angles2[0] (or sides and sides2) you might see something like 1.490000003 and 1.49000001 which your cout hides from you because it rounds them.

Answer (score 0):

The congruency test used in this code is:

> If three sides of one triangle are equal to three sides of another triangle, the triangles are congruent.

and for similar triangles is:

> If two triangles have two of their angles equal, the triangles are similar. [..] When two angles are equal, all three angles must be equal.

Both these rules imply the particular arrangement of elements isn't important, just that they must be equal when they contain all the same elements, irregardless of the ordering). ie. (`{3,1,2} == {1,2,3}` .

Sorting the arrays first (`std::sort`) just makes it easier to compare ( as soon as one pair of sides or angles are not equal, you know the triangles can't be congruent/similar ), which is checked in the line `if(angles1[i]!=angles2[i]){ return false;}`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Forgot to do it myself.